# Multi-line PCRE w\ lookhead, count matches

Tags: perl, regex, regular-expressions, pcre

I am trying to perform a regex that matches if both the word cat AND dog are in the regex with multi-line support

```
matches

cat asdjfaldsfj dog
####
does NOT match

cat adfasdf8989
####
matches

dog adlsjf88989 cat
####
matches

cat asdf8a89sdf8
a sdf asd f ads f ads fasdf
dog  a dsf ads fads f
asdfadsfadsf
```

The regex I'm using is pretty simple

```
/^(?=.*\bcat\b)(?=.*\bdog\b).*$/gs
```

The problem is that this only finds the first occurrence since it is greedy.  I really want the following to count two matches but it only matches once

```
cat asdf8a89sdf8
a sdf asd f ads f ads fasdf
dog  a dsf ads fads f
asdfadsfadsf
cat asdf8a89sdf8
a sdf asd f ads f ads fasdf
dog  a dsf ads fads f
asdfadsfadsf
```

Even without the second set of cat STUFF dog STUFF the regex still matches until the end.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints, but not a complete answer.

`.*` with `/s` is going to eat everything until end of string. Switching to the non-greedy `.*?` though will match a minimal string; the lookaheads are not forced into the match. My usual strategy for handling that is including anchors in the lookaheads, but multiline matching makes this difficult.

`/m` will be required if you want to match multiple times within the same string and still use `^$` anchors. Otherwise they match only the beginning and end of string.

Unless you really need a general-case solution, it's probably worth trying one manually ordering your subpatterns, eg:

```
(?gsmx)(?(DEFINE)
  (?<a>\bcat\b)
  (?<b>\bdog\b)
)
^.*?(?:
      (?&a).*?(?&b)|  # cat before dog
      (?&b).*?(?&a)   # dog before cat
    )[^\n]*
$
```

There's some really interesting things you can do with recursive subpatterns and relative backreferences but I wasn't able to structure them into a general case for N lookaheads without the number of steps skyrocketing into the 10k+ range.